# How to Get Array Value in File Using PHP

Tags: php

I have a php file where I've set up variables. Here's a sample of the file:

```
<?php
...
$users["Visitor_p"]=array("set1"=>"blank1","set2"=>"blank2");
```

EX when I print_r $uarr:

```
Array(
[0] => <?php
...
[17] => $users["Visitor_p"]=array("set1"=>"blank1","set2"=>"blank2");
)
```

**I've included the file and assigned it to:
$uarr**  i.e. $uarr = myfile.php

I loop through the lines using this to find the correct line:

```
$p = 'Visitor_p';
for ($v = 0; $v < $lncnt; ++$v) { // $lncnt is # of lines in the file
  $cline = $uarr[$v];
  if (strpos($cline, $p) !== false) {
    // get value of set1 here
  }
}
```

How do I get the set1 value using php?

Comment: Is this text file? are you sure the "set1" key and its value on the same line? maybe it will be better to convert to PHP array rather then working with string...

Comment: That's not a valid array definition so you can't access it, it throws a _parse error_. It's not even similar to an array definition so its not a typo.

Comment: @dWinder  Yes, it's a .php text file.  Yes, the key and value are on the same line

Comment: @AbraCadaver  How would I write the line in the file?

Comment: I don't know I can't really tell what you're trying to do.  Show the file not the `print_r`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver  I'm trying to get the value of set1, which is blank1.

Comment: Hi. The downvote (wasn't me) is because it isn't clear what you are trying to do. People want to help. The `include` statement is missing so it is not clear how you set `$uarr`. Thanks to @AbraCadaver for making some assumptions and getting you a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if `file1.php` is a PHP array definition then it's simple:

### file1.php

```
<?php
$users["Visitor_p"] = array("set1"=>"blank1","set2"=>"blank2");
```

Just include it and access the array:

### file2.php

```
<?php
include('file1.php');
$p = 'Visitor_p';
echo $users[$p]["set1"];
```

Comment: Thanks - appreciated.  Sure wish other people wouldn't mark down questions that are asked in good faith - If the orig. poster new exactly what to ask & post then there would be no need to post at all ;)